# Can a number be given the attribute 'physical'?

Tags: numbers, concept

This question initially arose while translating a technical document from German. The original text was 'physikalische Heizzonenummer', literally 'physical heating-zone-number'.

My immediate reaction was to think of heating zones which are numbered 1 to n but which can be addressed in other 'logical' ways. However, the German does seem to mean that the number itself is 'physical'. For me, a number is a concept and cannot be physical (except for those digits you can screw on to your front door). You can have a group of physical apples or heating zones but a number allocated to each one is surely in itself not physical itself.

Am I wrong here? Perhaps the original German is a bit clumsy and imprecise but it just set me wondering about the concept of numbers. I would be interested to hear other opinions :-)

Comment: Is the Heating Zone 'physical'?

Comment: @user11761 - there are physical heating elements in the machine arranged in zones. So I guess the zones are physical. To be honest I don't know how they might be logically organised. Perhaps they can be grouped (e.g. as pairs) and then addressed logically rather than physically

Comment: Can you first elaborate on what exactly is heating-zone-number? I'm in no way an expert in German and can't understand the meaning from just literal translation of one short phrase.

Comment: Is the heating zone physically labeled with the number? (That would be similar to those digits for your front door).

Comment: @Philoto - that's really my point. See the second paragraph. I would say that you can enumerate physical and logical objects but a physical number itself makes no sense

Comment: @D Krueger - I wondered that too but what would be the 'logical' alternative?

Comment: @paul well, generally, the attribute *physical* can be attached to a number (actual telephone numbers are sometimes called *physical numbers*, *physical number of something* can mean the number of physical instances of said something as opposed to virtual ones).

Comment: I’d have to see more context to say anything with any real confidence, but my first interpretation, despite the compound *Heizzonenummer*, would be 'the number of a physical heating zone'.

Comment: @paul It may not be 'logical', but 'conceptual'. For instance, you might locate 'heating zone 5' by referring to a schematic to find it. So even without a physical number, everyone still knows what 'heating zone 5' is.

Answer (score 1):

Can we? Probably not. A number is an abstract object, not a real thing, and we can't give an abstract idea/object the description of a physical object.   A [number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number), as defined by Wikipedia is:

> A number is a mathematical object used to count and measure. A notational symbol that represents a number is called a numeral but in common use, the word number can mean the abstract object, the symbol, or the word for the number

A [mathematical object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_object) is an abstract object.